# NuGet or assemblies folder for shared 3rd party DLL's?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, nuget

I have about 10-15 projects with separate solutions that reference 3rd party DLL's in a microsoft .NET shop. One of the problems that we want to address is consistency of the versions of the DLL's used across projects (E.G. Netwonsoft 8.0.3 in all projects as opposed to separate versions depending when the project was created).

I have seen this done in two separate ways in my previous positions and was wondering if there are any other options to solve this problem.

1. I have used a corporate NuGet for all third party DLL's referenced within a solution for any project within the company. The DLL's would be updated and then made available to the developers in the projects to pull down and upgrade (if needed) within the solutions on their own.
2. Another company had an assemblies folder in source that housed all "approved" third party DLL's and all references lived within this directory.

I did see this question but it only offered one of the two solutions above: [Where should you store 3rd party assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733762/where-should-you-store-3rd-party-assemblies)

Are there other options aside from the ones listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever possible use NuGet. Primary reason being that Git doesn't very much handle large binaries well and using LFS for this doesn't make much sense, since there is a valid alternative. TFVC has fewer issues with large binaries, but I'd keep future migration to Git in mind if you're on TFVC.

Keep in mind that not just NuGet, but likely also npm and other package sources are of interest in this case.

If you want to enforce a certain version being used, create a custom task that you hook into the CI pipeline. That way you can easily give off warnings or setup some kind of policy. The custom task could take the packages.config file, scan the referenced packages and then query the TFS/VSTS package management feed to see if it's using the latest version (or the is using the latest minor version)... (or is using at least x versions back)... or fetches the approved versions from a json file or xml file from somewhere and validates against that...

Comment: Using NPM was one of the things that I had considered as being a possible stumbling block for our future projects and referenced assemblies. Do you think that a corporate NuGet server would be a better solution to help mitigate this problem in the future? To be honest, I am not that familiar with Node or NPM yet, still getting the handle on how all of that works.

Comment: I recommend setting up your own NuGet server using Proget or using the TFS2017 package management feature.

Answer (score 0):

In your source control, Commit and Push to Master with the desired dependency DLLs when the repository is first populated.   Since all users, even on other branches, will then be pulling from the repository, you're ensuring they receive all the DLLs they need.  This only becomes a problem if you're referring to DLLs in the GAC,  which is resolved either by GACUtil or just making sure everyone is using the same Windows version.